# .htaccess redirect old domain to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I use from `http://siteold.com/json/` in my application and can not change it.
and my new domain is `http://panel.sitenew.com/json/` . how redirect my old url to new url without change in application ?

this way does not work (in siteold.com) :

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect http://siteold.com/json/ http://http://panel.sitenew.com/json/
```

Comment: Is your redirect file under the title `htaccess.txt`? Many OS's cannot support  the `.htaccess` extension, so you are better off uploading to the server befor e renaming to `.htaccess`.

Comment: my file name is .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to redirect a URL to another URL. You will have to create a `htaccess.txt` file to the directory of the website you want to redirect, and then use this code

```
Redirect /siteold.com/json/ http://panel.sitenew.com/json/
```

This will redirect the old file path to the new file path. You cannot add `http://` to the origin domain as the code doesn't work like that.

[Source](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file)